# Storing GML Polygon in PostGIS 2, ERROR: unknown spatial reference system

Tags: postgis, polygon, xml, gml

I am receiving GML as part of a larger XML message. When I receive the XML it is unmarshalled to Java objects. I have no rights to alter the schemas or the generated Java code. Therefore, I later have to marshal the OpenGIS polygon back to XML. When I try to store it in the PostGIS database, I get the following exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unknown spatial reference system

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO test (polygon) VALUES (ST_GeomFromGML('
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <ns1:Polygon srsName="http://metadata.ces.mil/mdr/ns/GSIP/crs/WGS84E_3D" ns1:id="P1" xmlns:ns6="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:ns5="http://release.niem.gov/niem/external/ogc/xls/1.1.0/dhs-gmo/2.1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:ns3="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
    <ns1:exterior>
      <ns1:LinearRing>
        <ns1:pos>32.23426 -110.34511 90.2</ns1:pos>
        <ns1:pos>32.23435 -110.34544 90.2</ns1:pos>
        <ns1:pos>32.23444 -110.34555 90.2</ns1:pos>
        <ns1:pos>32.23426 -110.34511 90.2</ns1:pos>
      </ns1:LinearRing>
    </ns1:exterior>
 </ns1:Polygon>', 4326))
```

If I try to remove the SRID from the query, I get the same exception.
The column I try to store the polygon in, looks like this:

```
AddGeometryColumn('test', 'polygon', 4326, 'POLYGON', 3);
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: A GML pos should just have an x and y, no? Looking at the [docs](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGML.html), I see you can insert polyhedral surfaces, but you need to specify it like `<gml:posList srsDimension="3">0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0</gml:posList>`, ie, with a srsDimension. I accept that this might seem unlikely from the error message, but worth checking.

Comment: If you have the GML unmarshalled already, you might want to consider using JTS and insert the geometries directly as spatial objects, and avoid the overhead of GML. Just a thought :D

Comment: I tried adding `srsDimension="3"`, but it didn't help. However, I found out that if I change the srsName to `srsName="EPSG:4269"` it works. I could override that attribute, but I will try to fix it otherwise first.

Comment: I am open to try alternative solutions. I briefly looked into JTS, and that is definitely an option. My current polygon object is a `net.opengis.gml._3.PolygonType`, do you have any idea on how I can convert it to a JTS polygon?

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570017/how-to-create-a-polygon-in-jts-when-we-have-list-of-coordinate. I don't know how to directly cast from one type to another, but if you have the coordinates, you can simply build the geometry from that.

Comment: Does removing the z value above remove the SRID error, btw?

Comment: Removing the z value did not remove the SRID error. But adding `gmlPolygon.getValue().setSrsName("EPSG:4326");` fixes the problem. I also found out like you said that I need to add `srsDimension="3"` to polyhedral surfaces as well to avoid getting: ERROR:  invalid GML representation.

Comment: So, you have a working solution now then?

Comment: For now, yes, thank you very much! I do however need to support 2D polygons in the future as well, and I haven't received the final specification on which srsNames I could possibly get. If it can be anything other than WGS84 I have a problem. But I think I can manage from here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
Explicitly set the correct srsName `gmlPolygon.getValue().setSrsName("EPSG:4326");` 
I also had to add srsDimension to the points since they had x, y, z: 
`<ns1:pos srsDimension="3">32.23435 -110.34544 90.2</ns1:pos>`